# How to estimate the value of this integral

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to use this property:

if $m \le f(x,y) \le M$ for all $(x,y)$ in $D$, then

$ mA(D) \le \iint_{D}\ f(x,y) \ dA \le MA(D)$.

To show that:

$0 \le \iint_{D} \ sin^4(x^3 + y^3) \ dA \le 1x10^{-3}$

where D is the triangle enclosed by the lines $y = \frac{1}{2} - x$, $y = \frac{1}{2} + x$ and $y = 0$.

But I can't find $0$ and $1x10^{-3}$ for the edges. I found $6,04 x 10^{-5}$ in place of $0$ and $9,37 x 10^{-4}$ in place of $1 x 10^{-3}$.

I'm stuck, so any tip will be helpful

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have solved it!

You seem to be saying that $6.04 \times 10^{-5} \le \iint_{D} \ sin^4(x^3 + y^3) \ dA \le 9.37 \times 10^{-4}$

Since $0<6.04 \times 10^{-5}$ and $9.37 \times 10^{-4}=0.94 \times 10^{-3}\le 1\times10^{-3}$,

you can say that $0\le 6.04 \times 10^{-5} \le \iint_{D} \ sin^4(x^3 + y^3) \ dA \le 9.37 \times 10^{-4}\le 1\times10^{-3}$

or, as required, $0 \le \iint_{D} \ sin^4(x^3 + y^3) \ dA \le 1\times10^{-3}$